# Delay the application closing of windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to delay the application closing event in windows phone. What i trying to achieve is, i need to send a web request(for sending the usage time of application) for achieving analytics in my application. So based on my current implementation before complete sending the request the main thread exits and application closes. What is the alternative to fix this issue. I cannot send the request in next application start(this fix i am not expecting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Closing`event of the application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx

But you have a maximum of 10 seconds to send your data, after that os will kills your application.
The best scenario is to try to send the data and flag as send if it's ok before 10s, if not, you will need to send the data at the next launch.

Comment: I am asking about windows phone not windows 8.. =e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral(); is not available in windows phone 8

Comment: My mistake, I mixed both but the part about 10s is still valid and the answer is still the same, you need to save/send everything on that method before 10s

Comment: Closing or deactivated events. Be careful calling async here. Process might not wait for the async method to finish.

Comment: Use the closing event to save the data locally, and then use the activating event to submit the data to the remote server the next time the application is started.